# Android 8.0 DownloadManager not working in MOBILE DATA

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I Set this in download manager but it does not work even in WIFI:

```
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWO‌​RK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
```

And This code below can work: **BUT ONLY IN WIFI MODE** so that It can NOT download using MOBILE data

```
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWO‌​RK_WIFI)
```

Is this a bug in Download Manager?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Actually, I found that remove this line will work.

Comment: Have you found the root cause yet?

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem. But removing line of `setAllowedNetworkTypes` doesn't work.

My problem can be reproduced on 8.1 emulator. But it works well on a real device.

My solution is to `setAllowedOverRoaming(false)`. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Check network availability, especially the wifi/mobile signal icon on statusbar. If a little cross is there, the system will treat it as no net and will not proceed downloading(I've encountered this recently).

Answer (score 1):

Change Android Manifest permission external write permission like below,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="replace"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the developer says:

```
setAllowedNetworkTypes

added in API level 9
public DownloadManager.Request setAllowedNetworkTypes (int flags)
Restrict the types of networks over which this download may proceed. By default, all network types are allowed. Consider using setAllowedOverMetered(boolean) instead, since it's more flexible.
```

So just remove this line will work.

Comment: According to Doc, I remove this line to set it as DEFAULT behavior.